# Как правильно объявить переменную recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно объявить переменную recyclerview ?

```
package com.example.recyclerview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null

     private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null

     private var recyclerview: ?????  <----
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager (this)
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Да хоть так же как и остальные: `private var recyclerview: RecyclerView? = null`. Только вот надо ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
```